# ExtJS v3 - access data from grid panel inside a form panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, formpanel

I have a GridPanel that I am using inside a Form.

When I submit the form, I have no problem grabbing the data from the form elements but cannot read/see the data that is placed inside the grid.

(Bascially, I am giving them an area to add email addresses in the grid).

I'm thinking I can just set the grid panel data as a hidden value in the form but that didn't work as I thought.

What direction should I take here so when someone submits the form I can see the main 'reason' field (which I can right now) and also each of the Email addresses that they are entering.

(I am submitting the form via a button that uses POST).

```
var projection_record = Ext.data.Record.create([
    { name: 'Email'}
]);

var projections_store = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({
        idIndex: 0
    }, projection_record)
});

var projections_grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: projections_store,
    columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'Email',
        header: 'Approval Email',
        sortable: false,
        width: 250,
        editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
            valueField: 'displayText',
            displayField: 'displayText'
        })
    },
    {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        header: "Delete",
        width: 150,
        items: [{
          icon: 'images/delete.png',
          handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = store.getAt(rowIndex);
                    alert("Delete " + rec.get('Email') + " ?");
                }
          //handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colindex) {
              //var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
              //var id = record.get("Email");
              //window.location = '<% $base %>storage_approval_delete/' + id;
          //}
       }]
     }
    ],
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Approvers',
        icon: 'images/Add.png',
        handler: function(){
            var projection = projections_grid.getStore().recordType;
            var p = new projection({
                Email: ''
            });
            projections_grid.stopEditing();
            projections_store.insert(0,p);
            projections_grid.startEditing(0,0);
        }
    }],
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    trackMouseOver: true,
    stripeRows: true
});

var simpleForm = new Ext.FormPanel ({
    labelWidth: 175,
    id: 'simpleForm',
    url:'./manager_approvals',
    method: 'POST',
    frame:true,
    title: 'Ada a New Project',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 850,
    defaultType: 'textfield',

    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Request Information',
            name: 'Description',
            xtype: 'textarea',
            allowBlank: true,
            anchor:'100%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Approving Managers',
            autoHeight: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            collapsible: false,
            collapsed: false,
            items: [projections_grid]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'hidden',
            name: 'hidden1',
            value: projections_store
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... I would seriously think about adding a comma separated field for a list of emails ....

If you are hell bent on letting them submit a form and edit a grid at the same time (good luck getting your users to understand what they need to do) what you need to do is on submit: lookup the store backing your grid, get the data values from the store records (iterate), extract the values you need, join with a comma, and finally either set a hidden field or just include as a parameter.

Good luck.

Comment: there has to be a way to assign the store to a variable to be passed.

I have tried these 

value: Ext.util.JSON.encode( projections_store.getRange(), 'data' )

//value: projections_store.getRange().json

//value: Ext.util.JSON.encode( projections_store )

//value: Ext.util.JSON.encode(projections_store.data.items, 'data')

Comment: what do you mean assign? You need that data to be 'referenced' not stored into a hidden field. The data might change, but the hidden field will NOT be updated even if you succeed in setting some value to it on form load.